# CircleCI Build Error - Firebase CLI and Node.js Compatibility

Tags: android, node.js, github, circleci, firebase-tools

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I hope this message finds you well. I'm encountering an issue with my CircleCI build for my personal project, specifically related to the compatibility between Firebase CLI and Node.js versions. Unable to update the node.js version although I did set the configuration in config.yml file. I've searched for tips and info related to this matter but I wasn't able to find a solution.

The following is the error message

```
Firebase CLI v13.0.0 is incompatible with Node.js v16.16.0
Please upgrade Node.js to version >=18.0.0 || >=20.0.0
Exited with code exit status 1
```

[Error image I got at CIrcleCI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA8qY.png)

I've attempted to address this by updating the config.yml file in the following way but still get the same error.

```
# ... (other configuration)

- run:
    name: "Update Node.js"
    command: |
      curl -sSL "https://nodejs.org/dist/v18.16.0/node-v18.16.0-linux-x64.tar.xz" | sudo tar --strip-components=2 -xJ -C /usr/local/bin/ node-v18.16.0-linux-x64/bin/node
      node --version
      npm --version

- run:
    name: output updated node version
    command: node -v

- run:
    name: Update PATH
    command: |
      echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> $BASH_ENV
      source $BASH_ENV
      which node
      node --version

- run:
    name: Install Firebase CLI
    command: |
      curl -sL https://firebase.tools/bin/linux/latest -o firebase-cli
      chmod +x firebase-cli
      ./firebase-cli
      firebase --version
# ... (other configuration)
```

Unfortunately, these changes haven't resolved the issue. I'm seeking guidance or examples from the community on how to properly address this Firebase CLI and Node.js compatibility problem in my CircleCI build.

Any assistance or tips you could provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time and expertise.

Comment: Same error here, started just today. GitHub Actions, `node -v` is `v20.10.0`, installing `firebase-tools` in this way: `curl -sL firebase.tools | bash`. Perhaps something is wrong in the [newest version of tools release 13 hours ago](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v13.0.0).

Comment: I've submitted a bug report: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/6586

Comment: Thank you for the bug report. I'll keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue in the auto-installer. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/6586#issuecomment-1845675868

A quote from a contributor:

> builds from firebase.tools come bundled with Node JS (this is why they 'just work' out of the box). While releasing 13.0.0, we originally wanted to package node 20 - however, one of the tools we use to do this does not support Node 20. While trying to fix this, it seems like I accidentally built with Node 16 instead.